# How to get JetBrains Rider to show the opening bracket line?

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

I get this functionality by default with WebStorm. On clicking a closing bracket, it temporarily displays the line with the opening bracket on top of the editor (if the line is not within the viewport) and hides it when I click somewhere else. I don't have to jump to the matching opening bracket to see it.

[image]

I have no idea what this functionality is called and I looked up many possibilities and couldn't find anything. Please help!

Comment: I looked around the Preferences dialog, and I wasn't able to turn this functionality _off_. I can see it working with C# and Razor views with default settings.

Doesn't it work for you for all files in Rider, or any specific extensions?